# Soap character encoding in Android

Tags: android, soap, encoding, character-encoding

I can call webservices via the code that I am sharing below and it's ok but while I am sending a value to parameter with turkish characters there is coming up an encoding problem. When I change the encode charset utf-8 to iso-8859-9, some turkish chars get correct displayed (ç, ö, ü) but 3 letters (ı, ğ, ş) does not change. why does this happen?

abcçdefg**?**h**?**ijklmnoöprs?tuüvyz
must be: abcçdefg**ğ**h**ı**ijklmnoöprs**ş**tuüvyz

```
final DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient(); HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 15000);
        // set parameter
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpClient.getParams(), true);

        // POST the envelope
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(parameters[0]);
        // add headers
        httppost.setHeader("soapaction", parameters[1]);
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=iso-8859-9");

        String responseString="";
        try {

            HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(parameters[2]); 
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // extended class from BasicResponseHandler
            ResponseHandler<String> rh=new ResponseHandlerTr();

            responseString=httpClient.execute(httppost, rh); 

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("exception", e.toString());
        }

        // close the connection
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return responseString;
```

Comment: try:
`httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");       
...     
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);         
responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");` it works with polish chars

Comment: @njzk2, I did not put whole code. parameters[2] refers envelope struct in HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(parameters[2]);

Comment: @Selvin, I can get the result without any problem. The problem occurs when I start inserting to db that received value. Should I check the webservice side?

Comment: inserting to db ... but where on server side ? if yes, than yes you should check webservice code (or settings web server settings)

Comment: @Selvin I changed all utf-8 to iso-8859-9 on server side. but it keeps displaying with wrong chars :(

Comment: In additional when I check the webservice on the serverside there is no problem. The problem appears only while using android.

Comment: how about changing all back to utf-8 and add parameter to constructor: `new StringEntity(parameters[2], "utf-8");`

Comment: @MustafaGüven please write up an answer. If you don't want to spend the time, then consider deleting the question.